# How do I enable internet-style quoting in Outlook Web Access?

Tags: email, exchange, outlook-web-access

How can I enable [internet-style quoting](http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/email-style.html) in Outlook Web Access? I have found [several](http://www.slipstick.com/mail1/quote.htm) [guides](http://blogs.pcworld.com/tipsandtweaks/archives/007360.html) on [how to](http://mailformat.dan.info/config/outlook.html) enable it in Outlook but not a single one on Outlook Web Access. We are running version 8.1.

I cannot access the server using Exchange/IMAP externally. This is providing significant problems for me now since I have to spend a lot of time editing long e-mails before sending replies.

Comment: You do not need IMAP access if you have Outlook, of course.  You can add the Exchange server and user details into Outlook, if you have Outlook.

Comment: I forgot to mention that I'm accessing the server externally and the only way to do that is via OWA.

Comment: You do not have to use OWA to access Exchange externally.  You only have to use it if Outlook is not available to you and you do not have to be on the same LAN.  If you go to the Options area in OWA and go to About, you can get your mailbox server name.

Comment: @jason404: The problem is that I'm not using windows at home so I cannot run Outlook and since there is no IMAP I cannot use my preferred client either.

Comment: In that case, you're probably best off using another client to connect to Exchange.

Comment: Unbelievable. It's 2016 and you still can't reply inline using the Outlook Office356 web interface. I use Linux and am absolutely *not* going to install Windows or Outlook in Wine just to reply inline.

Comment: Things continue to be ugly: https://outlook.uservoice.com/forums/284136-outlook-com/suggestions/15055500-add-ability-to-quote-original-email-when-replying

Answer (score 15):

No, you **cannot** do email quoting in OWA. That being said, you can use Firefox with the [It's All Text!](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/its-all-text) add-on to open the text in a text editor and then add the quoting prefix there. From [Fix Outlook Quoting Style](http://ilkka.github.io/blog/2011/01/31/fix_outlook_quoting_style):

> 1. In OWA, choose to reply to a message. Horribly quoted message text appears.
> 2. Use It’s All Text or some other similar tool to open message text in a reasonably smart editor.
> 3. Filter entire message text through this script. E.g. in Vim type `:%!path-to-script.rb`, after making the script executable of course.
> 4. Replace original mesage text with output of filter. If using It’s All Text, just type `:wq`.
> 5. Presto! Correctly quoted message. You might have to move your sig, though.
>
> That’s how to use it, now here’s the script:
>
> ```
> #!/usr/bin/env ruby
> # Fix outlook quoting. Inspired by perl original by Kevin D. Clark.
> # This program is meant to be used as a text filter. It reads a plaintext
> # outlook-formatted email and fixes the quoting to the "internet style",
> # so that::
> #
> #   -----Original Message-----
> #   [from-header]: Blah blah
> #   [timestamp-header]: day month etc
> #   [...]
> #
> #   message text
> #
> # or::
> #
> #   ___________________________
> #   [from-header]: Blah blah
> #   [timestamp-header]: day month etc
> #   [...]
> #
> #   message text
> #
> # becomes::
> #
> #   On day month etc, Blah blah wrote:
> #   > message text
> #
> # It's not meant to alter the contents of other peoples' messages, just to
> # filter the topmost message so that when you start replying, you get a nice
> # basis to start from.
> require 'date'
> require 'pp'
>  
> message = ARGF.read
> # split into two parts at the first reply delimiter
> # match group so leaves the delim in the array,
> # this gets stripped away in the FieldRegex if's else clause
> msgparts = message.split(/(---*[\w\s]+---*|______*)/)
> # first bit is what we've written so far
> mymsg = msgparts.slice!(0)
> # rest is the quoted message
> theirmsg = msgparts.join
> # this regex separates message header field name from field content
> FieldRegex = /^\s*(.+?):\s*(.+)$/
> from = nil
> date = nil
> theirbody = []
> theirmsg.lines do |line|
>   if !from || !date
>     if FieldRegex =~ line
>       parts = line.scan(FieldRegex)
>       if !from
>         from = parts.first.last
>       elsif !date
>         begin
>           DateTime.parse(parts.first.last)
>           date = parts.first.last
>         rescue ArgumentError
>           # not a parseable date.. let's just fail
>           date = " "
>         end
>       end
>     else
>       # ignore non-field, this strips extra message delims for example
>     end
>   else
>     theirbody << line.gsub(/^/, "> ").gsub(/> >/, ">>")
>   end
> end
>  
> puts mymsg
> puts "On #{date}, #{from} wrote:\n"
> puts theirbody.join("")
> ```

Comment: It seems that the "It's All Text!" Firefox extension does not exist any more (or that the link is broken).

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I did --

Copy the part of the message you want to quote, scroll back up to your reply, and then click the "quote" button (under "message" toolbar), then paste it in.

[image: Outlook web formatting toolbar with "quote" button highlighted]

The pasted message appears with a default style of a grey bar to the left; in order to insert replies inside the quoted text, just put the cursor there and hit enter or return a few times to break out of the quoting and put in your inline replies:

[image: Email message showing quoted parts interspersed with unquoted inline replies in Outlook 365 OWA web app; text is quotes from Bhagavad-Gita Chapter 2]

This is on Outlook Web App hosted on outlook.office365.com; not sure how to check which version, but I believe it's a current version as of this writing (Aug 2023).  Hope that is helpful.  Wish it was more built-in, but at least it is not too hard and doesn't require any additional software or plugins.

Comment: This is actually the best answer, as it's actual quoting in an actual reply, even though you can't set up quoting by default.

Answer (score -1):

Assuming that you are using Linux, here are a couple of alternative email clients which you could try:

Gnome: [Evolution](http://projects.gnome.org/evolution/) - This definitely works, but connecting to Exchnage through OWA.

KDE: [Kontact](http://userbase.kde.org/Kontact) - It appears that this works with older Exchange servers.

Comment: Thank you for the answer but I really would like to be able to do this from OWA instead of using client software as I usually access it using a browser.