# Plain-text replies with greater-than in Outlook PWA

Tags: linux, google-chrome, email, microsoft-outlook, progressive-web-app

In my organisation, accessing mail from Linux computers is possible with the Chrome Outlook progressive web app.

With the Windows version of Outlook it is possible to set the reply option to `always convert to plain text` and then start the lines of the original messages with `>` (according to Wikipedia this is known as [UseNet quoting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Usenet_quoting)).

For some reason, this option does not seem to be as easily available in the PWA version version of Outlook. Ideally, I would like to be able to use the most traditional way of Usenet Quoting: 'reply-to-mail' has `>` and 'reply-to-reply' has `>>`, etc.

Could this be done in Outlook PWA in any way, perhaps by manually editing Chrome/Outlook config files?

Comment: There is no native way to enable internet-style quoting in the PWA, which is a progressive web version of Outlook. See: https://superuser.com/questions/204224/how-do-i-enable-internet-style-quoting-in-outlook-web-access

Comment: Thanks - that is a *very* old post. So In Outlook it is possible but not in the PWA. Is the fact that this is a progressive web version an explanation why the quoting does not work? I'm not sure what the term means.